# How to extract the data from a consecutive xml tag attribute based on the previous tag value

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have trouble getting my regex right for the below use case.

```
<LOB>
            <LOBStatusInfo>
                <LOB>Mobile</LOB>
                <Status>Active</Status>
            </LOBStatusInfo>
            <LOBStatusINfo>
                <LOB>Voice</LOB>
                <Status>Active</Status>
            </LOBStatusInfo>
            <LOBStatusInfo>
                <LOB>Internet</LOB>
                <Status>Disconnect</Status>
            </LOBStatusInfo>
        </LOBStatus>
```

In the above XML, I'm looking to extract only the status corresponding to Voice (which is active).

So far, I was able to get the LOB itself, but not the corresponding status.

ps: I'm a newbie, please pardon if the details weren't enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't parse XML with regex, check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
Instead, you can use [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and a proper `xml` parser. What is your environment, language ?

## Test :

### Input file

```
 <LOB>
    <LOBStatus>
        <LOBStatusInfo>
            <LOB>Mobile</LOB>
            <Status>Active</Status>
        </LOBStatusInfo>
        <LOBStatusInfo>
            <LOB>Voice</LOB>
            <Status>Active</Status>
        </LOBStatusInfo>
        <LOBStatusInfo>
            <LOB>Internet</LOB>
            <Status>Disconnect</Status>
        </LOBStatusInfo>
    </LOBStatus>
</LOB>
```

### Command

(just an example, now in shell, but the query can be used in any language of your choice)

```
xmllint --xpath '//LOB[text()="Voice"]/../Status/text()' file.xml
```

or

```
xmllint --xpath '//LOB[text()="Voice"]/following-sibling::Status/text()' file.xml
```

### Output:

```
Active
```